# Last part of the folder path + filename

Tags: bash, find

I want to print with format `Folder/Folder`.

Instead of full paths:

```
/volume1/ArtWork/Folder1/folderA
/volume1/ArtWork/Folder1/folderB
/volume1/ArtWork/Folder2/folderA
/volume1/ArtWork/Folder2/folderA
```

I want to print in a txt "semi-paths" (not only filenames!):

```
Folder1/folderA 
Folder1/folderB
Folder2/folderA
Folder2/folderA
```

This is what I am currently using:

```
find /volume1/ArtWork/* -type d -maxdepth 2 \
    -not -empty -printf '%f\n' \
    > /volume1/ArtWork/filenamesdir.txt
```

(I want to print not-empty folders, but the format at the moment is wrong)

Comment: this seems like a task for `awk`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to navigate to that folder before running the `find` command. Using `-printf '%P\n'` you can print the part of interest, each on a separate line:

```
pushd /volume1/ArtWork
find . -type d -maxdepth 2 -not -empty -printf '%P\n'
popd
```

Note that I'm using `pushd`/`popd` instead of `cd`. That makes changing into the directory and back to the previous one more convenient.

Comment: from which `bash` version are `pushd` and `popd` supported? Can;t seem to find it in GNU bash 4.1.2

Comment: That sounds odd. It works even with pretty old bash 3.1.x on MacOS. If you really shouldn't have it, then you need to use good old `cd`

Comment: How do you have search for `pushd` and `popd`? Its in bash itself: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
find /volume1/ArtWork/* -maxdepth 2 -type d \
-exec sh -c 'echo $0 | grep -o "[^/]*/[^/]*$"' {} \; \
> /volume1/ArtWork/filenamesdir.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a gnu-sed version:

```
find /your/path -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 |
xargs -0 -I{}  bash -c 'sed -r "s/.*\/(.*\/.*)$/\1/" <<<"{}"'
```